# How do I import a full webpage into Excel using the Data From Web tab?

Tags: excel, scroll, web-scraping, vba

I am looking to import a webpage into Excel, which is easy enough using the Data/From Web tab. However, the page needs to be scrolled down to the bottom of the webpage in order for all the data to be pulled. At the moment, the import is working well, but only pulls in the first page of the webpage. Which is why I am stuck.

So is there a way to do get the whole webpage into Excel? (And then record a macro so that this can be done for any webpage)

Thanks

Comment: Can we know the webpage?

Comment: yes, all the webpages I want to import are of this format:

http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/8048/commentary/1082591/sunrisers-hyderabad-vs-royal-challengers-bangalore-1st-match-ipl-2017

Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to do a subrotuine to scroll down all the time. You can do it with VBA, the problem is how to check you are already at bottom of page

Comment: any ideas how to create the subroutine?